# Robotium project and maven

Tags: android, maven, robotium, android-maven-plugin

I tried to create an android test project using Robotium as testing framework and maven as builder. But, is it necessary for my android application to use maven as builder ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not per se need Maven. As a matter of fact, the [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started) of Robotium gives a basic example of how to do this in just Eclipse.

Now, would life be better when using Maven. I generally like "yes" for an answer to that question. Testing is only one part of your iterative development, and it is great to have all your steps automated. Doing that with Maven allows you to leverage the entire lifecycle that it offers for your project from test driven development, perhaps in an IDE, to packaging and deployment. And the [Android Maven Plugin](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/index.html) fits into that approach.